# How to close an ajaxi page in main page with a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have 2 pages. In the first page I have a div (ajaxicall), inside that div, another page is loaded.

My problem is how can I close the second page when I click in "close" that is in the second page and show containers of my first div again?
tnx

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ajaxicall">
    <span id="addtobasketspan">First Div</span>
    <img src="images/shopping-cart-xxl.png"/>
  </div>

<script>
  $("#addtobasketspan").click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
       url:'secondpage.html',
       type:'get',
       data: 'lid=1',
       success:function(data){
          $("ajaxicall").load('secondpage`enter code here`.html');
       }
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: then in this case events should be delegated.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of that page?

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/acc33fm3/

jQuery

```
$("#addtobasketspan").click(function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    //url: 'secondpage.html',
    type: 'get',
    data: 'lid=1',
    success: function(data) {
      //$(".second-div").load('secondpage`enter code here`.html');
      $(".second-div").append('<button class="close-div">X</button>');
    }
  });
});

$(document).on("click", ".close-div", function() {
  $(this).closest('div').hide();
});
```

Just append a button into your ajax page and then use that to simply hide the ajax `div`

Answer (score 0):

You should have an element in the second page, like a close button to close that page, and to make the first page to default look. It can be like;

```
<a href="#" id="close">close</a>
```

And you may bind a code to that id like;

```
$("#close").click(function(){
    $('#ajaxicall', window.parent.document).html('
        <span id="addtobasketspan">First Div</span>
        <img src="images/shopping-cart-xxl.png"/>
    ');
});
```